# Parametrized BigQuery query produces no results from a joined table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have rather a complex query that creates a table based on the inner join. The query is created by Python code and SQLAlchemy. When the query runs the result in the destination table is missing data from the right joined table.

To find out why I did the following:

1. Located the specific query in "Query History" of the BQ Console.
2. Using the Job associated with the query I have fetched the Job JSON file.
3. I have substituted all the parameters (@) in the query text with their literal values.
4. Loaded the resulting SQL text into the BQ editor and executed the query.

To my surprise, the data from the joined table are now present in the result.

The chance that this stems from a bug in BQ is very slim. I think the difference is in the way I substitute the values of the parameters when recreating the query.

The specific query parameters are either "STRING" or "INT64". Here is a sample from the query JSON file:

```
          {
            "name": "PARAM_802c1f6dd32747238ccdf80b305a4fd1",
            "parameterType": {"type": "INT64"},
            "parameterValue": {"value": "0"}
          },
          {
            "name": "PARAM_f7ad61d9a6414d0ea8560e097950ecbc",
            "parameterType": {"type": "STRING"},
            "parameterValue": {"value": "`column`"}
          },
```

These are the rules I follow for replacing "@param*":

- if a parameter is INT64 I use the value from the JSON "as is" (without quotes)
- if a parameter is STRING, I check whether it is surrounded by back ticks or not. If surrounded I use it "as is", if not, I add surrounding single quotes to the value.

Would be glad to hear from experts what can be wrong with my approach or anything else that can help me in solving (or debugging) my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems my problem was that I have tried to use a column name as a value and this is not supported. Here is an excerpt from the documentation:

> Parameters cannot be used as substitutes for identifiers, column names, table names, or other parts of the query.